# Sliding pins - Text position

Tags: php, html, css

I need to get this meny done, but the programmers say it's not possible to do what I want.

I find it hard to believe, so I'm asking you guys if this is possible.

Check out this page: http://www.nsquareit.com/lottemcgill/
Click the "Archive" in the menu below the logo. Here you can slide the three pins to make a selection to search for. The text that displays the selected value for each slider is now following the pin itself. I want that text to be static on the right side of the pins.

Is this possible?

He says the dealbreaker here is that the logo and menu itself should have fixed position. The logo and menu should not scroll with the page itself, but rather say where it is at all times. (like it is now).

So, is this possible? I believe it is. I cant see why not..?

Thanks =)

Comment: what do you mean by static text

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/XevZRR38X1Bg

Like this. But I managed to get it done by changing some css with firebug. This is a working solution, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/, it's easy to use, customizable and you can place it anywhere you want (including fixed elements)